# Start second project after first project has started in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Working on a client server solution. Client is one project, server another project. Currently running two instances of vs 2010 one for client and one for server. Manually running server waiting for it to start. Then running client. So far so good. You can start multiple projects in the same sln and I could use this feature but I really want to start the client prj only after the server prj has started. Can I do this ? Worst case is there some way I can delay start of second project by x secs so I can use just one sln. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Start Options" of your client project and configure it for run the server first ("Start external program")

Comment: I need to run the server as a proj (not ext program) for debugging. Problem is I need the second proj (client) to start AFTER the server is running. Need a configurable delay of x secs between start of two projects.